# Mongoid find_and_modify deprecated

Tags: mongoid, mongoid5

I'm currently updating a Rails app to Mongoid 5. I've having trouble updating some code that uses a deprecated method (find_and_modify). Any help would be appreciated.

In Mongoid 4, I have this method to find and upsert:

```
LineItem.where({
  date: Date.today,
  location: "Location",
  department: "Department"
}).find_and_modify({
  "$set" => {
    hours: 8,
    updated_at: Time.current
  },
  "$setOnInsert" => {
    account_id: ObjectId("5739f4534f4e48b2aa00091c"),
    date: Date.today,
    location: "Location",
    department: "Department",
    created_at: Time.current
  }
}, upsert: true)
```

What is the equivalent using Mongoid 5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/docs/tutorials/mongoid-upgrade.txt) changelog:

`find_and_modify` has been removed and replaced with 3 options: `find_one_and_update`,
`find_one_and_delete` and `find_one_and_replace`.